# Need references for study of fundamental group of 3-manifold

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, algebraic-topology, manifolds, 3d

Can anyone provide references on the study of the fundamental group of 3-manifolds?

The references should be geared for a physicist that has good knowledge of differential geometry and group theory, but is not very proficient in the latter.

Comment: You should also read some algebraic topology, namely, fundamental groups and covering spaces,  for instance "Algebraic Topology: An Introduction" by Massey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been studying fundamental groups of 3-manifolds lately, and one of my main references has been Hempel's book *3-Manifolds* (Amer. Math. Soc., Vol. 349, 2004), which although somewhat heavy in its content, discusses a lot about the group-theoretic properties of fundamental groups of 3-manifolds.

Otherwise, there's Aschenbrenner et. al.'s *3-Manifold Groups* (Zürich: European Math. Soc., Vol. 20, 2015) which is a nice survey of various things known, which in itself contains a myriad of references about the subject.

If you want the differential geometry side of things, Hempel deals with $I$-bundles over surfaces and the like, and if you want the knot theory side of things, then either Rolfsen's *Knots and Links* (Amer. Math. Soc., Vol. 346, 2003) is a very accessible text, as is Prasolov & Sossinsky's *Knots, Links, Braids and 3-Manifolds* (Amer. Math. Soc., No. 154, 1997).

There is much overlap in the above texts, and in my opinion Hempel is the most intense read, but the most rewarding, while Prasolov & Sossinsky give a very hands-on approach with lots of beautiful pictures.